Are events from the newspapers with a hint of CogSci on-topic?
Just now, I saw the following post on [skeptics.se]:
https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/35904
The question regards an accident in aerospace, which may be linked to a lack of sleep. This is a human-factors issue, which is a cognitive science. However, I could image that the context of the question (news item, one-time event) may not fit the focus of CogSci for some. What are your thought? 

I think these type of questions could be interesting. They are specific to a set of set of circumstances like self-help questions. However, the question would typically be of more general interest. 
I imagine such questions would be more about the application of psychological theory to the specific situation. As such the evidence would be different to the typical question asked here where answers are often readily drawn by looking at specific studies that map onto the question.
So in short, I think questions that ask about how psychological theory could explain a particular event in the news could be good for this site.
